# In asp.net core jwt token authentication working with expire token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I have implemented basic token-based authentication in my asp.net Core web API project. I used JWT for authentication. I installed NuGet packages Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer. I follow [this article](https://codepedia.info/jwt-authentication-in-aspnet-core-web-api-token) step by step. The article code works fine if I set expire value as 10 mins.

I need to set the value as 1 minute or 2 minutes. I write code   `Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1)`. But after 1 minute complete the token still is valid.

```
Code: public Tokens Authenticate(Users users) {
  // other code here    
  var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
  var tokenKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iconfiguration["JWT:Key"]);
  var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor {
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, users.Name)
    }),
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
  };
  var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
  return new Tokens {
    Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)
  };
}
```

---

Startup.cs code

```
  services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Key"]);
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {                 
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Key)                  
                };
               
            });
```

Comment: Please show your configuration for consuming the token.

Comment: this only code to generate token, In appsetting configuration Iuse below value, here xxx are some different value
 "JWT": {
    "Key": "xxxxxxxx",
    "Issuer": "xxxxx",
    "Audience": "xxxxx"
  }

Comment: OK, but how do you validate the token?

Comment: Using [Authorize] attribute over controller it validate, same i follow this https://codepedia.info/jwt-authentication-in-aspnet-core-web-api-token

Comment: most probably a clock skew issue, see accepted answer in the linked Q/A

Comment: Then you are presumably using the authentication system in ASP.NET Core. Please look in your Startup.cs and provide the configuration code you have there for consuming these tokens. At the moment you have only shown the code for generating them.

Comment: In above they user app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication middleware, but i use only app.AddAuthentication

Comment: There isn't only one way to set up the validation parameters for validating JWT tokens. Without seeing how _you_ have it configured, it's impossible to answer your question. If you don't want to provide that, then I can't help you.

Comment: @Llama i added more code from startup cs. in accepted answer they use middleware my approach is different

Comment: Then your problem is the same one as jps linked to. The default value for `ClockSkew` (a property of `TokenValidationParameters`) is 5 minutes. Meaning that tokens will be accepted for 5 minutes after they expire. If you don't want that, you should set `ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44252312/3181933).

Comment: Ok i add ClockSkew  and check

Comment: @Llama: thanks adding ClockSkew  solved the problem, but this is strange cause ideally setting Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1) should override all default setting. Can you help me with refresh token, flow of refresh token after is expire

Comment: then please confirm that the linke Q/A answered your question (click on "yes, it answers..."). And please don't add new questions in a comment. Search for existing Q/A covering your refresh token topic and ask a new question, when you don't find an answer.

Comment: You're looking at this the wrong way. Setting `Expires = someValue` is for _generating the token_. The other code is for _validating the token_. Sometimes the server receiving the token will not be the one that generated it. For example, we use Identity Server for authentication, and that's on a completely separate server and domain to our application code that validates the token. In such scenarios, setting some degree of `ClockSkew` may be desirable if the server clocks differ.

Comment: ok will do it and create new question on refresh token